# How convert a Photoshop made logo into CSS properly?

Tags: html, css, photoshop

I am trying to convert a logo made into Photoshop in CSS.
As i am no master of both, i've tried but greatly failed by using the Photoshop build in "copy css" function.

I've tried to redo the CSS via my limited knowledge, but failed miserably.

[image: logo]
[image: ps copy css output]

```
.Group_5 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
  z-index: 47;
}
.Group_4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: -2px;
  top: -2px;
  width: 1924px;
  height: 1084px;
  z-index: 46;
}
.Ellipse_3 {
  border-width: 6.25px;
  border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1119px;
  top: 486px;
  width: 168.5px;
  height: 174.5px;
  z-index: 45;
}
.Ellipse_2 {
  border-width: 6.25px;
  border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1122px;
  top: 505px;
  width: 139.5px;
  height: 139.5px;
  z-index: 44;
}
.Ellipse_1_copy {
  border-width: 6.25px;
  border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1109px;
  top: 512px;
  width: 139.5px;
  height: 139.5px;
  z-index: 43;
}
.Ellipse_1 {
  border-width: 6.25px;
  border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1091px;
  top: 492px;
  width: 176.5px;
  height: 176.5px;
  z-index: 42;
}
.Shape_26 {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1358px;
  top: 409px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 7px;
  z-index: 41;
}
.Shape_25 {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1347px;
  top: 409px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 17px;
  z-index: 40;
}
.Shape_24 {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1394px;
  top: 409px;
  width: 11px;
  height: 7px;
  z-index: 39;
}
.Shape_23 {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1385px;
  top: 408px;
  width: 21px;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 38;
}
.Shape_22 {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1386px;
  top: 430px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 37;
}
.Group_2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
  z-index: 36;
}
.Shape_16_copy_2 {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1395px;
  top: 410px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 26px;
  z-index: 35;
}
.Shape_16_copy {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1384px;
  top: 419px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 25px;
  z-index: 34;
}
.Shape_16 {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1346px;
  top: 419px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 25px;
  z-index: 33;
}
.Shape_15 {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1346px;
  top: 439px;
  width: 46px;
  height: 8px;
  z-index: 32;
}
.Shape_19 {
  border-width: 4.167px;
  border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1357px;
  top: 407px;
  width: 37.666px;
  height: 0;
  z-index: 31;
}
.Shape_21_copy {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1344px;
  top: 407px;
  width: 19px;
  height: 18px;
  z-index: 30;
}
.Shape_21 {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1383px;
  top: 407px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 18px;
  z-index: 29;
}
.Shape_20 {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1395px;
  top: 409px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 7px;
  z-index: 28;
}
.Shape_18 {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1346px;
  top: 417px;
  width: 46px;
  height: 8px;
  z-index: 27;
}
.Shape_17_copy {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1381px;
  top: 408px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 19px;
  z-index: 26;
}
.Shape_17 {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1384px;
  top: 428px;
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  z-index: 25;
}
.Group_1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
  z-index: 23;
}
.Rectangle_1 {
  border-width: 4.167px;
  border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1325px;
  top: 472px;
  width: 48.666px;
  height: 19.666px;
  z-index: 22;
}
.Shape_10 {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1132px;
  top: 656px;
  width: 11px;
  height: 8px;
  z-index: 21;
}
.Shape_9 {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1394px;
  top: 423px;
  width: 41px;
  height: 242px;
  z-index: 20;
}
.Shape_8 {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1132px;
  top: 451px;
  width: 271px;
  height: 213px;
  z-index: 19;
}
.Shape_11 {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1132px;
  top: 450px;
  width: 17px;
  height: 8px;
  z-index: 18;
}
.Shape_7 {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1132px;
  top: 416px;
  width: 64px;
  height: 41px;
  z-index: 17;
}
.Shape_14 {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1427px;
  top: 417px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 215px;
  z-index: 16;
}
.Shape_13 {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1393px;
  top: 415px;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  z-index: 15;
}
.Shape_12 {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1144px;
  top: 416px;
  width: 302px;
  height: 42px;
  z-index: 14;
}
.Group_3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
  z-index: 11;
}
.Shape_3 {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 577px;
  top: 684px;
  width: 710px;
  height: 12px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.Shape_2 {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 571px;
  top: 301px;
  width: 137px;
  height: 403px;
  z-index: 9;
}
.I {
  font-size: 283.333px;
  font-family: "Kozuka Gothic Pr6N";
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transform: matrix( 1,0,0,0.76592618857706,0,0);
  -webkit-transform: matrix( 1,0,0,0.76592618857706,0,0);
  -ms-transform: matrix( 1,0,0,0.76592618857706,0,0);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1043.001px;
  top: 406px;
  z-index: 7;
}
.C_copy_2 {
  font-size: 283.333px;
  font-family: "Kozuka Gothic Pro";
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transform: matrix( 1.04227845443354,0,0,0.87676868039824,0,0);
  -webkit-transform: matrix( 1.04227845443354,0,0,0.87676868039824,0,0);
  -ms-transform: matrix( 1.04227845443354,0,0,0.87676868039824,0,0);
  position: absolute;
  left: 869.507px;
  top: 406.5px;
  z-index: 6;
}
.C {
  font-size: 283.333px;
  font-family: "Kozuka Gothic Pro";
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transform: matrix( 1.04227845443354,0,0,0.87676868039824,0,0);
  -webkit-transform: matrix( 1.04227845443354,0,0,0.87676868039824,0,0);
  -ms-transform: matrix( 1.04227845443354,0,0,0.87676868039824,0,0);
  position: absolute;
  left: 711.507px;
  top: 406.5px;
  z-index: 5;
}
.Shape_4 {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 685px;
  top: 289px;
  width: 98px;
  height: 212px;
  z-index: 4;
}
.Shape_1 {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 693px;
  top: 309px;
  width: 89px;
  height: 191px;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

I might be just missplacing something, or the given CSS result is not working properly, as anything i do and/or try results into a blank page.

I am not exactly sure how i could get this logo converted, as mentioned above i am no master in both.

The logo is made of circiles/lines and the 2"C" texts.
Some of the layers have masks on them for transparency (where they overlap)

It's not the best made, as it was supposed to have the same thickness overall, but i would like a way to get into CSS form.

Comment: Looking forward to have the logo made just via CSS, no images or anything else.
*Also edited and added the given CSS from PS

Comment: would it be possible to have the logo exported from photoshop in SVG? That might be a better idea if what you're going for is scalability. Why do you require CSS?

Comment: SVG is better technology to keep your logo together exactly how you see it in Photoshop. Then it is just one object in your site, can be targeted with CSS to position and size it how you like.

Comment: As @Neil said, SVG would be a better option. You can import your image into Illustrator, and vectorise it. Then illustrator is able to export as SVG.

Comment: SVG would be an amazing option too, but would still prefer to have it in CSS, main reason to have it CSS, i would just like. But adding the fact i'm not really able to do it myself properly, i'll probably end up with the SVG option.